# How to clear memory properly?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have the following code

```
Vehicle v=  new Vehicle();
Car car = v.getCar();
v.clear();
```

The clear() in vehicle is

```
clear()
{
    car=null;
}
```

I am trying to ensure that after I call `clear()` , no one else gets access to the car object. I can set it to null like I do above, but it doesn't stop anyone else from holding the reference to it, and can still access the memory location to get the data in there.

I dont want to call `System.gc()`

The use case is , after logout, i need to clear everything stored in the memory. also the storage mechanism is a singleton. Even if I avoid using singleton, this problem persists

Comment: You can keep 'car' private and return defensive copies in the getter methods. [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10951820/1089811) that might be useful on the topic.

Comment: What can be gained by returning defensive copies? It can only make matters *worse* as far as memory occupation is concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you provide a reference to a foreign caller, you can forget about any hope of managing the lifecycle of its referent. Calling `System.gc()` will be just as futile because the garbage collector does not touch reachable objects.

You must design your application such that you never expose the references to the objects you want deallocated on logout. Usually this is a quite tall order so you should think twice whether it is really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `System.gc()` wouldn't help you anyways. It's not meant to be called by the program, and it has very little effect (yes, in some cases it is justified, but that's rare).

If you give out a reference somewhere, you can never know who holds it. Of course you could try some skullduggery with `WeakReferences`, but that wouldn't help, since you can get the strong reference out of it.

Your only chance is to design your program so that you don't give out references, otherwise you can't prevent others from holding on to them.

Answer (score 0):

How do you imagine this working? What if another thread is using the object when you want to clean it up? Does it just disappear mid-operation for it? `System.gc()` will not do anything for you in this case - if there is a reference GC will not clear it, and if there are none, it will clear it later anyway.

The only and proper way to make sure an object will be cleared out of memory in Java is through solid design, by which you stop holding on to an object when you no longer need it (not talking about JVM bugs right now). If you want to clear memory on logout, then clear references everywhere on logout.

A bit extra control can be achieved through Soft, Weak or Phantom references, as in you can keep the object and that will not prevent GC, but you cannot force GC on a specific object.